# Change WooCommerce price for session

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce

I am trying to change the price of certain items if the customer is a returning visitor. I'm running a redirect to www.website.com/welcomeback/ through Adobe Target to sense if the customer is returning.

I want to change the price of an item only for the welcome back user's session, not actually change the price in the DB.

So normally Product ID #43 would be 1500.00, but a returning visitor will see a "special" price of 1,450.00.

Is this possible within WooCommerce?

---

Additional information:

- The user is not logged in
- The product is discounted before cart for "returning" users
- When a user come to the web site, a session is created at the beginning, to track him
- Coupons can't be used (they are already used  for affiliate discounts).
- Additionals discounts should be applied to new "returning" users price.

Comment: Some question: is user logged in? Is product discount on cart session (the product is in cart already)? An other way should be a special coupon auto applied if customer session is detected…

Comment: I have update your question with that useful information. What are you using for affiliates 5if you are using additional plugins for WooCommerce, it could be important to mention them, if they change the WooCommerce behavior. Last important thing, could you provide the code that you use for creating that session entrance, editing your question? (May be yo can delete some of your comments now)…